# Export Jar runnable in Eclipse with output function to an xml file

Tags: java, xml, swing, jar, export

I am exporting a Swing application to a runnable Jar in Eclipse. The Swing application takes some inputs and write it to a XML file, which I hard coded the location to be "C:/runnable/example.xml".

It works fine in Eclipse but when I deploy the app, I don't know where the generated XML goes. Can somebody tell me how I can write some data to an external file in a runnable JAR?

Comment: If you hardcoded the location of the output XML file, then don't you expect it to go there?

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that it was the permission issue. Now I have fixed it with a relative path and directory. Thanks whiskeyspider!

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody tell me how I can write some data to an external file in a runnable JAR?

Write the output to a (sub-)directory of `user.home`.  That is a path that is stable across runs and should be writable by the app.